# Why does my grammar reports EOF error when I don't have this token?

Tags: c#, antlr4

My grammar:

```
grammar gdx;

// parser rules
firstname : STRING;
lastname : STRING;
name: firstname SPACE lastname;

// lexer rules
STRING: [a-zA-Z]+;
SPACE: ' ';
```

And c# code:

```
var inputStream = new AntlrInputStream("John Smith");
var lexer = new gdxLexer(inputStream);
var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new gdxParser(tokens);

var tree = parser.name();

IList<IToken> allTokens = tokens.GetTokens();
foreach (var token in allTokens)
    Console.WriteLine($"Token: '{gdxLexer.DefaultVocabulary.GetSymbolicName(token.Type)}', Text: '{token.Text}', Line: '{token.Line}', Column: '{token.Column}'");

Console.WriteLine("Person:");
Console.WriteLine($"firstname {parser.firstname()}");
Console.WriteLine($"lastname {parser.firstname()}");
```

Produces following output:

```
Token: 'STRING', Text: 'John', Line: '1', Column: '0'
Token: 'SPACE', Text: ' ', Line: '1', Column: '4'
Token: 'STRING', Text: 'Smith', Line: '1', Column: '5'
Token: 'EOF', Text: '<EOF>', Line: '1', Column: '10'
Person:
line 1:10 missing STRING at '<EOF>'
firstname []
lastname []
```

**What I understand (I think)**:

- Based on the token output I conclude that tokens are correctly parsed
- Both first and last names are represented by lexer rule STRING
- EOF is implicitly processed by antlr, so I don't have to specify it in the
  grammar

**What I don't understand:**

- The error "line 1:10 missing STRING at
- How to make parser recognize firstname and lastname as such, and not through the lexer rule. Also, I can't find the explanation in antlr book, I know it is there, I just can't find it. I'll appreciate it if someone who knows the book let me know the chapter. Thanks!

Comment: You are calling the parser three times: `parser.name()`, `parser.firstname()`, `parser.firstname()` (again). You should only call the parser once. Then, refer to data in `tree`. That is why you get the parse error. 
 Generally, your grammar should always contain an EOF-terminated start rule to force the parser to consume all input.

Comment: Or, if it is necessary to do another call (e.g. when reusing a parser), rewind your input and token streams first, to make parsing start at the beginning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: you've already parsed the tokens and cannot do that again. Do it like this:

```cs
var inputStream = new AntlrInputStream("John Smith");
var lexer = new gdxLexer(inputStream);
var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new gdxParser(tokens);

// By calling `name()` you are instructing the parsers to consume 
// 3 tokens (`STRING`, `SPACE` and `STRING`). After doing so, the
// parser is at the end of the input: hence the error you receive
// about the built-in EOF token.
var nameNode = parser.name();

Console.WriteLine("Person:");

// Since the name rule:
//
//     name: firstname SPACE lastname;
//
// uses `firstname` and `lastname` rules, you can call the methods 
// `firstname()` and `lastname()` on the name-node.
Console.WriteLine($"firstname {nameNode.firstname().GetText()}");
Console.WriteLine($"lastname {nameNode.firstname().GetText()}");
```